# iOS: reducing space between two cells : UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have multiple cells (prototype cells) in my UITableViewController. I want to reduce the space between the subsequent cells to almost negligible, so that it appears like a continuous list of items. How can this be done? Please suggest the best way.

Comment: TableView cells don't have any spacing between them. What is your exact problem?

Comment: Set tableview separator color to that of the cell background color.

Comment: please check are you adding cell in section view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you meant the `separator` between cells. It's the property of Table View.

You can do this from your code:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
```

Or you can set this property in the Interface Builder too:
[image: Table View Separator Style]

Answer (score 1):

As @Shubham pointed out... table view cell don't have space between them.

[image]

Maybe you have a problem caused by other things such as separators (you can see it in the image as well), section header, subviews of the cell.